# Mongoose Query Population does not work with mongoose v6.0.13

Tags: mongoose, populate

When Mongoose query population was used in NodeJs an error was thrown:
TypeError: req.user.populate(...).exePopulate is not a function
The version of Mongoose that was installed was the latest 6.0.12.

Then I reinstalled Mongoose: npm i mongoose@5.3.16
the program works fine

Can someone advise if I should install the latest version of Mongoose?

Comment: you could use `$lookup` instead of populate

Comment: can you please elaborate? example?